# How to force QCompleter to check second word in QLineEdit

Tags: qt

I have a feature to implement a textbox with auto completion.
I have found a code which uses QLineEdit and QCompleter.

Hence I have my string values, "one" , "two" , "three" ect.

Once I type "on" the completer suggests me every word in the list with prefix "on".
But after I select "one" from the list and try to type the second word, completer does not work.

Is there a functionality in QCompleter or overall in Qt, which provides such functionality. I haven found it in documentation.

See my found code:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include<QStringList>
#include<QLineEdit>
#include<QCompleter>
#include<QHBoxLayout>
#include<QWidget>
#include<QLabel>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QWidget *win=new QWidget();
    QHBoxLayout *lay=new QHBoxLayout();
    QStringList wordList;
    wordList << "alpha" << "omega" << "omicron" << "zeta"<<"america"<<"orion"<<"amit"<<"Odssey";
    QLabel *lbl=new QLabel("Select");
    QLineEdit *lineEdit = new QLineEdit();
    lbl->setBuddy(lineEdit);
    QCompleter *completer = new QCompleter(wordList);
    completer->setCaseSensitivity(Qt::CaseInsensitive); //Make caseInsensitive selectio
    lineEdit->setCompleter(completer);
    lay->addWidget(lbl);
    lay->addWidget(lineEdit);
    win->setLayout(lay);
    win->showMaximized();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: The QCompleter for QLineEdit does not check every word but the whole content. If your Strings would be "alpha omega" the completer would give you a hit for this string. You eventually should subclass QLineEdit and set up the implementation to use QCompleter on every word instead of the whole content.

Comment: And how to set the implementation for QLineEdit, for which QCompleter will check every word but the whole content?

Comment: I am sorry, but i right do not have the time to give you a full implementation for a QLineEdit-Subclass. Besides you can learn much more form it doing it on your own. Eventually you could set up QLineEdits completer to just recognize the last word written with the ``QCompleter::setCompletionPrefix(const QString &prefix);`` where prefix is just your last single word you want to complete

Comment: "how to set the implementation for QLineEdit" You probably need to  read [the source code for `QLineEdit`](http://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/widgets/qlineedit.cpp.html) and go from there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you need override several methods in QLineEdit. My version of code:

mclineedit.h

```
#ifndef MCLINEEDIT_H
#define MCLINEEDIT_H

#include <QLineEdit>

class MCLineEdit : public QLineEdit
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MCLineEdit(QWidget *parent = 0);
    void setMultipleCompleter(QCompleter*);

protected:
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *e);

private:
    QString cursorWord(const QString& sentence) const;

private slots:
    void insertCompletion(QString);

private:
    QCompleter* c;
};

#endif // MCLINEEDIT_H
```

mclineedit.cpp

```
#include "mclineedit.h"
#include <QCompleter>
#include <QTextCursor>
#include <QAbstractItemView>
#include <QScrollBar>

MCLineEdit::MCLineEdit(QWidget *parent) :
    QLineEdit(parent)
{
}
void MCLineEdit::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *e)
{
    QLineEdit::keyPressEvent(e);
    if (!c)
        return;

    c->setCompletionPrefix(cursorWord(this->text()));
    if (c->completionPrefix().length() < 1)
    {
        c->popup()->hide();
        return;
    }
    QRect cr = cursorRect();
         cr.setWidth(c->popup()->sizeHintForColumn(0)
                     + c->popup()->verticalScrollBar()->sizeHint().width());
    c->complete(cr);

}
QString MCLineEdit::cursorWord(const QString &sentence) const
{
    return sentence.mid(sentence.left(cursorPosition()).lastIndexOf(" ") + 1,
                        cursorPosition() -
                        sentence.left(cursorPosition()).lastIndexOf(" ") - 1);
}

void MCLineEdit::insertCompletion(QString arg)
{
    setText(text().replace(text().left(cursorPosition()).lastIndexOf(" ") + 1,
                           cursorPosition() -
                           text().left(cursorPosition()).lastIndexOf(" ") - 1,
                           arg));
}

void MCLineEdit::setMultipleCompleter(QCompleter* completer)
{
    c = completer;
    c->setWidget(this);
    connect(c, SIGNAL(activated(QString)),
            this, SLOT(insertCompletion(QString)));
}
```

To learn more visit http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/tools-customcompleter.html (with QTextEdit).

Answer (score 3):

Here I have found a solution.

```
#ifndef COMPLETER_H
#define COMPLETER_H
#include <QCompleter>
#include <QString>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QLineEdit>

class Completer:public QCompleter
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Completer(QStringList stringList, QObject *parent=0);
    virtual QString pathFromIndex(const QModelIndex &index)const;
    virtual QStringList splitPath(const QString&)const;

public slots:
    void onLineEditTextChanged();
private:
    mutable int cursorPos_;
};


class ExpressionLineEdit: public QLineEdit
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        explicit ExpressionLineEdit(QWidget *parent=0);
private:
    QStringList stringList;
    Completer *completer_;
};
#endif // COMPLETER_H

#include <completer.h>
#include <QDebug>
Completer::Completer(QStringList stringList, QObject *parent)
    : QCompleter(stringList,parent)
    , cursorPos_(-1)
{

}

ExpressionLineEdit::ExpressionLineEdit(QWidget* parent)
    : QLineEdit(parent)
{
stringList << "minRoute" << "minPitch" << "minSpacing";
completer_ = new Completer(stringList, this);
setCompleter(completer_);

    QObject::connect(this, SIGNAL(textChanged(const QString&)),
             completer_, SLOT(onLineEditTextChanged()));

    QObject::connect(this, SIGNAL(cursorPositionChanged(int, int)),
            completer_, SLOT(onLineEditTextChanged()));
}

QString Completer::pathFromIndex(const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    QString newStr = index.data(Qt::EditRole).toString();
    ExpressionLineEdit *lineEdit = qobject_cast<ExpressionLineEdit*>(parent());
    QString str = lineEdit->text();
    int prevSpacePos = str.mid(0, lineEdit->cursorPosition()).lastIndexOf(' ');

    int curPos = lineEdit->cursorPosition();
    int nextSpacePos = str.indexOf(' ', curPos);
    if (nextSpacePos == -1) {
        nextSpacePos = str.size();
}

QString part1 = str.mid(0, prevSpacePos + 1);
QString pre = str.mid(prevSpacePos + 1, curPos - prevSpacePos - 1);
QString post = str.mid(curPos, nextSpacePos - curPos);
QString part2 = str.mid(nextSpacePos);

    cursorPos_ = curPos + newStr.size() - pre.size();
    return part1 + newStr + part2;
}

void Completer::onLineEditTextChanged()
{
    qDebug() << "Completer::onLineEditTextChanged()" << cursorPos_;
    if (cursorPos_ != -1) {
        ExpressionLineEdit *lineEdit = qobject_cast<ExpressionLineEdit*>(parent());
        lineEdit->setCursorPosition(cursorPos_);
        cursorPos_ = -1;
    }
}

QStringList Completer::splitPath(const QString &path) const
{
     cursorPos_ = -1;
     ExpressionLineEdit *lineEdit = qobject_cast<ExpressionLineEdit*>(parent());
     QString text = lineEdit->text();
     QStringList stringList;
     QString str;
     int index = text.mid(0,lineEdit->cursorPosition()).lastIndexOf(' ');
     str = text.mid(index, lineEdit->cursorPosition()-index);
     str.trimmed();
     str.replace(" ", "");
     stringList << str;
     return stringList;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I needed something just like this! However in my testing I did notice some things, there are some things that you can get rid of (for example, *QString post* isn't actually used, it can be deleted). Also, there seems to be a bug in your implementation (at least from my testing), if you type in a list of words, then go back to type a word in the middle somewhere, if you use arrow keys to go up/down the autocomplete list, the first highlighted word will be placed in the correct position, but after that the cursor jumps to the end (regardless of the onLineEditTextChanged() slot), and then it starts replacing the last word with those from the autocorrect list.

I created my own implementation, one of the major differences is my implementation takes a *delimiter* character, and that character is used instead of always using a white space, and I fixed the bug that I described above. You'll notice my implementation is quite more simple:

**DelimitedCompleter.hpp**

```
#ifndef DELIMITEDCOMPLETER_HPP
#define DELIMITEDCOMPLETER_HPP


#include <QCompleter>


class QString;
class QStringList;


/**
 * class DelimitedCompleter
 *
 * QCompleter that supports completing multiple words in a QLineEdit, completed words are separated
 * by delimiter.
 */
class DelimitedCompleter : public QCompleter {
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        DelimitedCompleter(QLineEdit *parent, char delimiter);
        DelimitedCompleter(QLineEdit *parent, char delimiter, QAbstractItemModel *model);
        DelimitedCompleter(QLineEdit *parent, char delimiter, const QStringList &list);
        QString pathFromIndex(const QModelIndex &index) const;
        QStringList splitPath(const QString &path) const;

    private:
        char delimiter;
        mutable int cursor_pos = -1;

        void connectSignals();

    private slots:
        void onActivated(const QString &text);
        void onCursorPositionChanged(int old_pos, int new_pos);
};


#endif
```

**DelimitedCompleter.cpp**

```
#include "DelimitedCompleter.hpp"

#include <QDebug>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QStringList>


/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 *                              DELIMITEDCOMPLETER PUBLIC METHODS                                *
 * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */


DelimitedCompleter::DelimitedCompleter(QLineEdit *parent, char delimiter)
        : QCompleter(parent), delimiter(delimiter) {
    parent->setCompleter(this);
    connectSignals();
}


DelimitedCompleter::DelimitedCompleter(QLineEdit *parent, char delimiter, QAbstractItemModel *model)
        : QCompleter(model, parent), delimiter(delimiter) {
    parent->setCompleter(this);
    connectSignals();
}


DelimitedCompleter::DelimitedCompleter(QLineEdit *parent, char delimiter, const QStringList &list)
        : QCompleter(list, parent), delimiter(delimiter) {
    parent->setCompleter(this);
    connectSignals();
}


QString DelimitedCompleter::pathFromIndex(const QModelIndex &index) const {
    QString auto_string = index.data(Qt::EditRole).toString();
    QLineEdit *line_edit = qobject_cast<QLineEdit*>(parent());
    QString str = line_edit->text();

    // If cursor position was saved, restore it, else save it
    if(cursor_pos != -1) line_edit->setCursorPosition(cursor_pos);
    else cursor_pos = line_edit->cursorPosition();

    // Get current prosition
    int cur_index = line_edit->cursorPosition();

    /**
     * NOTE
     *
     * prev_delimiter_index should actually point at final white space AFTER the delimiter.
     */

    // Get index of last delimiter before current position
    int prev_delimiter_index = str.mid(0, cur_index).lastIndexOf(delimiter);
    while(str.at(prev_delimiter_index + 1).isSpace()) prev_delimiter_index++;

    // Get index of first delimiter after current position (or EOL if no delimiter after cursor)
    int next_delimiter_index = str.indexOf(delimiter, cur_index);
    if(next_delimiter_index == -1) {
        next_delimiter_index = str.size();
    }

    // Get part of string that occurs before cursor
    QString part1 = str.mid(0, prev_delimiter_index + 1);

    // Get string value from before auto finished string is selected
    QString pre = str.mid(prev_delimiter_index + 1, cur_index - prev_delimiter_index - 1);

    // Get part of string that occurs AFTER cursor
    QString part2 = str.mid(next_delimiter_index);

    return part1 + auto_string + part2;
}


QStringList DelimitedCompleter::splitPath(const QString &path) const {
    QLineEdit *line_edit = qobject_cast<QLineEdit*>(parent());

    QStringList string_list;
    int index = path.mid(0,line_edit->cursorPosition()).lastIndexOf(delimiter) + 1;
    QString str = path.mid(index, line_edit->cursorPosition()-index).trimmed();
    string_list << str;
    return string_list;
}


/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 *                              DELIMITEDCOMPLETER PRIVATE METHODS                               *
 * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */


void DelimitedCompleter::connectSignals() {
    connect(this, SIGNAL(activated(const QString &)), this, SLOT(onActivated(const QString &)));

    connect(qobject_cast<QLineEdit*>(parent()), SIGNAL(cursorPositionChanged(int, int)),
        this, SLOT(onCursorPositionChanged(int, int)));
}


void DelimitedCompleter::onActivated(const QString &text) {
    cursor_pos = -1;
}


void DelimitedCompleter::onCursorPositionChanged(int old_pos, int new_pos) {
    // If old_pos == cursor_pos then we are cycling through autocomplete list
    // If not cycling through autocomplete list, then make sure cursor_pos is reset to -1
    if(old_pos != cursor_pos) cursor_pos = -1;
}
```

Comment: I made several changes since I originally posted, and I think my implementation is basically bug free, and quite usable now, if anyone tries my code and finds bugs please let me know!

Comment: I like your solution because I don't have to change my QLineEdit but I had to change line 54 to `while (prev_delimiter_index < str.size() - 1 && str.at(prev_delimiter_index + 1).isSpace())` to avoid an out of bounds crash. Using Qt 5.12.2