# QCompleter supporting multiple items like stackoverflow tag field

Tags: python, pyside, qcompleter

Is there a way to make the QCompleter for pyside work more similar to how the Tag editor here on StackOverflow works? Where a user can type a word and then if there is a space it allows the autocomplete to display matching words?

This post seems like it does what i want but it's in C++
[How to force QCompleter to check second word in QLineEdit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21773348/how-to-force-qcompleter-to-check-second-word-in-qlineedit)

[image]

```
import os
import sys
import json
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui


class ExampleWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ExampleWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(300, 200)

        self.strings_model = QtGui.QStringListModel()
        self.get_data(self.strings_model)
        completer = QtGui.QCompleter()
        completer.setCaseSensitivity(QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        completer.setModel(self.strings_model)

        self.ui_input = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        self.ui_input.setCompleter(completer)
        self.ui_input.setPlaceholderText('enter description...')

        self.ui_tags_list = QtGui.QListView()
        self.ui_tags_list.setEditTriggers(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.ui_tags_list.setSelectionMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)
        self.ui_tags_list.setModel(self.strings_model)


        # main layout
        main_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.setContentsMargins(5,5,5,5)
        main_layout.setSpacing(5)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.ui_input)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.ui_tags_list)

        main_widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        main_widget.setLayout(main_layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(main_widget)

        # connections
        self.ui_input.returnPressed.connect(self.input_entered)


    def get_data(self, model):
        model.setStringList(["Animals", "Dogs", "Birds", "Cats", "Elephant", "Zebra"])


    def append_tag(self, val):
        if not val:
            return False

        if val.lower() in [x.lower() for x in self.strings_model.stringList()]:
            return False

        self.strings_model.insertRow(self.strings_model.rowCount())
        index = self.strings_model.index(self.strings_model.rowCount()-1)
        self.strings_model.setData(index, val)


    def input_entered(self):
        print 'selected word from drop down should be added to lineEdit'


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = ExampleWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must implement a logic that gets the last string, this will be the word to make the filter in the `QComplete` through `setCompletionPrefix()`:

```
class LineEdit(QtGui.QLineEdit):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtGui.QLineEdit.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.multipleCompleter = None

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        QtGui.QLineEdit.keyPressEvent(self, event)
        if not self.multipleCompleter:
            return
        c = self.multipleCompleter
        if self.text() == "":
            return
        c.setCompletionPrefix(self.cursorWord(self.text()))
        if len(c.completionPrefix()) < 1:
            c.popup().hide()
            return
        c.complete()

    def cursorWord(self, sentence):
        p = sentence.rfind(" ")
        if p == -1:
            return sentence
        return sentence[p + 1:]

    def insertCompletion(self, text):
        p = self.text().rfind(" ")
        if p == -1:
            self.setText(text)
        else:
            self.setText(self.text()[:p+1]+ text)

    def setMultipleCompleter(self, completer):
        self.multipleCompleter = completer
        self.multipleCompleter.setWidget(self)
        completer.activated.connect(self.insertCompletion)


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = LineEdit()
    completer = QtGui.QCompleter(["Animals", "Dogs", "Birds", "Cats", "Elephant", "Zebra"])
    completer.setCaseSensitivity(QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive)
    w.setMultipleCompleter(completer)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I'm not looking for them to add to the list, i just want them to add to the line edit.The list is only there so you know what items are available for typing

Comment: @JokerMartini Let's say that Ani has been written in the QLineEdit, with what event does it have to autocomplete, that is, which key has to be pressed ?, SO does not autocomplete, only gives suggestions, if you type pyt, it does not complete it until you press that option in the popup Explain in more detail what you want.

Comment: i would like it work more like the example seen on this webpage called Example 4. https://sean.is/poppin/tags/

Comment: I have seen that there is a problem in my code, that when I choose a second option, the first one is eliminated, is that what you mean?

Comment: yeah that is what the problem is. did you see the example i sent you in the webpage link

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: yeah that is exactly correct, i noticed it doesn't show Animals if i typed ani i have to type Ani. Where would i adjust it to ignore case sensitivity